# Could someone find any logic in the rigid body world and rigid body constraints behavior?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have a scene where I'm trying to find a logic for better understanding of rigid body world and rigid body constraints regularity. 
[image: The scene setup]

The setup seems work as I expected, but when I move the "Vert" object to the negative X direction or to negative Z the constraint on "Empty.007" doesn't move the "Circle" object and the "Circle" doesn't fall. I guess that happens when the "Vert" object gets out of the limits of the constraint. But I'm not sure because when I try to expand the limits it doesn't help.
Also I completely don't understand why the disabling the collision of the constrained objects (by "Disable Collisions" checkbox) in "Empty.007" makes the Circle object stay still.
And as you see I made a weird "Vert" object. That's because I didn't find a working way to bind the "Circle" object to Empty by a Rigid Body Constraint. Is it even exists or I must have a manifold Rigid Body for that?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably that are a bugs of Blender 2.83.6. It seems like all works as expected with Blender 2.91.